# Client-side asynchronous join of database tables

Tags: angularjs, node.js, promise

it's all day I'm trying to wrap my head around this problem.

I'm trying to extract an entity tree from a sqlite database, from an angularJS application, using nodejs as a shim that runs SQL queries generated from the client. I'm also using underscore.js.

I could flatten the entities to a table-like structure (array of objects which do not contain other objects) by using joins and "inflate" the rows to nested objects and arrays client-side, but I'd like to understand promises.  I could have used Spring with Hibernate and JPA, passing JSON from and to the server, but this is an experiment. I know it's not optimal on many levels.

**The problem**

tableA contains entities of type A. The same for tables B and C. Relationships in the database are: A has a set of B. Every B is paired with C. So, if I used Hibernate and Spring, I could ask for A and the server would have responded with an array of A, with every item containing an array of B, and avery containing a C.

**My implementation**

I want the function 'getAObjectDeep' to return a promise, and when I call success(callback) on the promise, the callback is passed a list of entities of type A, every entity containing an array of entities of type B, which in turn contain the matching entity of type C.

This is the code I wrote, which does not work. The problem is that when I call $q.all in the second promise, all entities of type A are lost, and the response is populated with an array of arrays of entities of type B, and when I call $q.all in the third promise, all entities of type B are lost, and the response is populated with an array of 'undefined'. *I can't control the output of $q.all, to pass to the next promise the value of the previous promise, enriched with the new rows obtained from the database.*

```
var queryDb = function(query) {
    return $http.get('/', {params: {sql: query}});
};

var getAObjectDeep = function(start, end) {
    return queryDb('SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE tableA.date >= \'' + start + '\' AND tableA.date <= \'' + end + '\' ORDER BY date DESC;')
    .then(function(response) {
        return $q.all(_.map(response.data, function(entityA) {
            return _.extend(entityA, queryDb('SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE idEntityA=' + entityA.id + ';'));
        }));
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        return $q.all(_.map(response, function(r) {
            var entityB = r.data;
            return _.extend(entityB, queryDb('SELECT * FROM tableC WHERE id=' + entityB.idObjB));
        }));
    });
}
```

Comment: Why you don't use `JOIN` instead of N+1 queries?

Comment: I don't think r.data exists since you have mapped the result in the previous code block r should be the current underscore  object

Comment: I think you still should ask the server for the complete, nested response - less traffic. Don't generate SQL queries on the client side and execute them on the server. You'd still use the same code with promises and all, but in nodejs not angular.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that `queryDb()` will return a promise in all three cases, and that responses are only accessible via promise methods, not directly.

The first use of `queryDb()` shows the correct pattern :

```
queryDb(...)
.then(function() {
    ...
});
```

But the second and third uses seem to assume an array - in any case something that `_.extend()` will operate on.

As far as I can tell, you need to turn the two innermost expressions "inside-out", and introduce a `.then()`.

```
var getAObjectDeep = function(start, end) {
    return queryDb('SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE tableA.date >= \'' + start + '\' AND tableA.date <= \'' + end + '\' ORDER BY date DESC;')
    .then(function(response) {
        return $q.all(_.map(response.data, function(entityA) {
            return queryDb('SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE idEntityA=' + entityA.id + ';').then(function(response2) {
                return _.extend(entityA, response2);
            });
        }));
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        return $q.all(_.map(response, function(r) {
            var entityB = r.data; //???
            return queryDb('SELECT * FROM tableC WHERE id=' + entityB.idObjB).then(function(response3) {
                return _.extend(entityB, response3);
            });
        }));
    });
}
```

From the async/promise perspective, this transform of the original code makes (more) sense.

The "join" logic is the same as that in the question. No attempt has been made to verify it except to say that `var entityB = r.data` may be incorrect as @vbranden point out; if it doesn't work, try `var entityB = r`.